# Why decltype expressions in return types have to be mangled in the symbol name?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14

I recently found out that decltype expressions are mangled as part of the functions symbol names, when used as return types, and that this can be the cause of nasty segmentation faults while demangling the expressions (in debugging sessions for example), if the expression is too complex.

The first version, using decltype in function return type, where the full expression gets mangled (http://goo.gl/EALubx):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

struct A { void bar() const; };

template<typename T>
decltype(std::declval<T>().bar()) foo(T const& a);

void foo() { A a; return foo(a); }
```

Is compiled to (GCC 5.2.0):

```
foo():
        sub     rsp, 24
        lea     rdi, [rsp+15]
        call    decltype ((((declval<A>)()).bar)()) foo<A>(A const&)
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```

The second version, almost equivalent, where the expression type is resolved as part of an additional template parameter (http://goo.gl/DfQGR5):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

struct A { void bar() const; };

template<typename T, typename R=decltype(std::declval<T>().bar())>
R foo(T const& a);

void foo() { A a; return foo(a); }
```

Is compiled to (GCC 5.2.0):

```
foo():
        sub     rsp, 24
        lea     rdi, [rsp+15]
        call    void foo<A, void>(A const&)
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
```

I understand that template functions can be overloaded on their return type only, but shouldn't the compiler be able to resolve the decltype expression on its own and mangle the resulting type instead?

Could anyone tell me about why, or point me where in the C++ specification it is specified?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that, it's just the name of the function. Actually, a  resolved return type would be a lot more confusing...

Comment: I believe that requiring to support arbitrary complex expressions in mangled names is not trivial, and that it imposes higher constraints on the demangler implementation. While I agree that it's an implementation problem, for example, GDB segfaults if the expressions are too complex.

Comment: Well, the compiler *could* emit the resolved information as well, helping other tools in the chain. My advice, be *extremely* patient... ( https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14441 )

Comment: You will never find a single word about mangling in the C++ standard, so any request for such is moot  by definition.

Comment: @SergeyA "Signatures are used as a basis for name mangling and linking." [defns.signature], latest WD

Comment: @Columbo, this is weird, I have not seen this quote before. In my honest opinion, it should not be there. It is entirely possible to create a 100% standard-conformant compiler without any mangling whatsoever.

Comment: If you mangle the resulting type, then you can't distinguish between `template<typename T> decltype(std::declval<T>().bar()) foo(T const& a);` and `template<typename T> decltype(std::declval<T>().baz()) foo(T const& a);` (say, in different TUs) instantiated over `struct A { void bar() const; void baz() const;};`.

Comment: Alright, but shouldn't both resolve to the same overloaded function as the resolved decltype is the same?

This also means that, assuming they are declared in different TUs and that ``bar`` takes an ``int`` argument, ``template<typename T> decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(1)) foo(T const& a);``, ``template<typename T> decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(2)) foo(T const& a);``, and ``template<typename T> decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(3)) foo(T const& a);`` are all different function overloads, although returning the same type?

Comment: Or weirder: ``template<typename T> decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(1+1)) foo(T const& a);`` and ``template<typename T> decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(2)) foo(T const& a);``

Comment: The templates in your example are "functionally equivalent but not equivalent", making the program ill-formed NDR. See [temp.over.link]/6.

Comment: But that's also the case for your example, no? ``decltype(std::declval<T>().baz())`` and ``decltype(std::declval<T>().bar())`` are "functionally equivalent but not equivalent" return types: both are resolved to void.

Comment: No, they are not functionally equivalent; the result are not the same for all possible values of `T`, unlike your case.

Comment: Alright, that sounds a good explanation, thanks.

Comment: You should do the answer as a separate post and accept it. Makes it easier to see ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ANSWER:**

As explained by [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) in the comments, the reason lies in the template function overload rules `[temp.over.link]/5-6`

For example:

```
// #1
template<typename T>
decltype(std::declval<T>().bar()) foo(T const& a);

// #2 same function as #1, because both are "equivalent":
// declared in the same scope, with the same name and 
// argument/return type expressions are "equivalent"
template<typename U>
decltype(std::declval<U>().bar()) foo(U const& a);

// #3 overloads #1, because argument/return type expressions
// may not be resolved to the same value for any given set of T
template<typename T>
decltype(std::declval<T>().baz()) foo(T const& a);
```

This also means that the following is ill-formed:

```
// #1
template<typename T>
decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(2)) foo(T const& a);

// #2 is "functionally equivalent" but not "equivalent" to #1
// because argument/return type expressions are not "equivalent"
// but "functionally equivalent": they are resolved to the same value
// for any given T
template<typename T>
decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(1+1)) foo(T const& a);
```